# Prelast element of a prolog list

Tags: prolog

Hi can someone help me with this problem in prolog:

I have this in prolog penultimo

```
([1,2,3,4,5],X)
```

and I have to get this

```
X = [1,2,3,5]
```

I have to delete the prelast elemnt of the list.

Please help me!

Comment: please, seichi, show some effort !

Comment: I had spend like 3hrs and i can't get it. I only can delete the last one... and i need the previous...

Comment: quitapenultimo([_|[]],[]):- !.
quitapenultimo([X|T],[X|W]):- quitaultimo(T,W). This only delete the last and i need to delete the prelast.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have two cases in your code, yes? - One for arriving at the end of the list, and one for handling the end of the list.

You know how to write the code to remove the Last element, right? -That's (typically) done in the "end" case, which looks at the last element, ignores it, and (typically) returns an empty list to be used as the basis to construct the answer list by recursion throught the previously called predicates.

Hint: Can you make the "end" case look at Two elements instead of one?

Comment: bravo! much better intuition +  hints instead of an answer

Answer (score 1):

of course, there are sever ways:

using append to deconstruct/reconstruct the list (inefficient):

```
delete_prelast(L, R) :- append(H, [_,X], L), append(H, [X], R).
```

from (amended) comment, more efficient:

```
quitapenultimo([_,X],[X]) :- !.
quitapenultimo([X|T],[X|R]) :- quitapenultimo(T,R).
```

yields

```
?- quitapenultimo([1,2,3,4,5],R).
R = [1, 2, 3, 5].
```

Comment: I have been working in this for the last 4 hrs... Thanks... Now i can go to sleep...

Comment: The important is not to solve your homework. The important is to understand the principle of lists manipulation in Prolog. If you understand that, you can solve your homework in seconds. Take a look http://boklm.eu/prolog/page_7.html   ;)